# MSSQL - Select NULL values on varbinary column

Tags: sql-server, null, varbinary

I am trying to do a select on a table with around 35.000 rows, one of the columns is a varbinary with may have some NULL values and I need to exclude those NULL values from my results.

The problem is: when you do a select on a varbinary column, it takes a lot of time to complete, I've found a way that I'm not sure I can use or is the best way to do something like that and I would like some opinions.

Here is it:

```
SELECT REQUEST,REQLOCATION,DESCRIPT,BLOBNAME,BLOBSIZE,substring(BLOBVALUE,0,1) AS BLOBVALUE,BLOBMODE,BLOBPATH,BLOBID,
REDIRID,ANALYST,CLIENT,SEVENT,PACKAGE,INSERTDATE
FROM REQBLOB WHERE substring(BLOBVALUE,0,1) IS NOT NULL
```

The `varbinary` column is the "BLOBVALUE" one where I do a "`substring`" select and this query gave me a result of 20.000 rows instantly and I think it's returned only valid data, not NULLs, what you think about that?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `SUBSTRING` in the `WHERE`, it's making your query non-SARGable; that's why it's slow.

```
SELECT REQUEST,
       REQLOCATION,
       DESCRIPT,
       BLOBNAME,
       BLOBSIZE,
       SUBSTRING(BLOBVALUE, 0, 1) AS BLOBVALUE,
       BLOBMODE,
       BLOBPATH,
       BLOBID,
       REDIRID,
       ANALYST,
       CLIENT,
       SEVENT,
       PACKAGE,
       INSERTDATE
FROM REQBLOB
WHERE BLOBVALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

*Why are you using substring on a `varbinary` anyway though..?*

Comment: Actually doing substring in the where clause is not making the query slow, it takes a lot of time if I do not use the substring in the query.

Comment: @JuninhoBill `SUBSTRING` will very likely slow your query down in the `WHERE`. If your query is still slow, then this suggests your query is bringing back a huge dataset, and you have no indexes which'll help your data engine. Is this guess correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we have a huge dataset with no indexes and I'm trying to solve this issue without the creation of indexes if it is possible, I'm not sure about that and this is why I have made this post here... Thanks!

Comment: @JuninhoBill You can check with execution plan suggestions.

Comment: Well there's your problem then  @JuninhoBill. If you have a huge dataset, and no indexes to help the data engine it's resorting to have to do a **full table scan**; of course that is going to me slow. If I gave you a 10,000 page book, where all of the pages had been jumbled up and asked you to return to me only the pages between 1000 and 2000 do you think you could do it quickly? What if they were ordered? I bet your answers are very different. it's the same for your data engine.

Comment: Why are you against building indexes? That is the real problem here.

Comment: @Larnu yes, you are absolutely right and I know that, just thinking if there is a way to have this working the way I thought...

Comment: @Larnu Yes, now I'm thinking to building indexes, just trying to see if there is another way... Thank you so much!!